# Problem in VS2010 IDE in analog monitor in a dual-monitor setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, multiple-monitors

I am using VS2010 Premium with a dual-monitor setup. One of the monitors is on a digital (DVI) cable and other one is on an analog (VGA) cable. I have noticed that when I put VS2010 in the analog monitor, there are garbled texts and refresh problems while coding and/or scrolling. This does not seem to be the case when I put VS2010 in the digital monitor. Note that, I am not expanding VS IDE to use 2 screens, just making it 1 full screen, either analog or digital.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

I also work with VS2008 and have not seen this problem in either screen. VS IDE has started using WPF from the 2010 release, not sure if this has something to do with it.

Edit: M/C information: The machine is an E6410 Dell laptop with Intel HD Graphics inbuilt. The monitors are connected through a docking station.

Final edit: Got resolved after I installed Win7. Guess it was a graphics driver issue, but I couldn't resolve it on Win XP Pro.

Comment: Sounds like a graphics driver issue to me. Are you seeing this problem only with VS, or with other WPF apps as well?

Comment: I do not know if I am running other WPF apps - how do I find out?

Answer (score 0):

check that the monitor has highest safe screen refresh rate. also, check for drivers.

"I do not know if I am running other WPF apps - how do I find out? "
Visual Studio 2010 is a WPF app.

Is your video card a "low end" card?

Comment: The refresh rates are at 60hz for the digital one and 75hz for the analog one (both at possible max). Pl. see the OP with updated m/c info. The driver is current and dated 4/2010. Regarding WPF app: I do not know if any other WPF app I am running (other than VS), so that I can compare the performance with VS. Thanks for replying.